# Issue using pg_dumpl

Tags: sql-server, heroku, connection, pg-dump

Ok, here's the issue: I want to upload a DB I've got locally and I'm using in localhost, but, when I use:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U root app_db > app_db.dump
```

I always get:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "app_db" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I think the problem is that I'm writing localhost instead of my heroku app address, can anyone tell me how can I get the correct address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have postgresql installed and running